# Difference for summation in maple

Tags: calculus, maple, differential

When calculate the differential respect to $x$ with Maple, I got this result.

$$\frac{d^4x^\lambda}{dx^4} = \frac{x^\lambda\cdot \lambda\cdot(\lambda-1)\cdot(\lambda-2)\cdot(\lambda-3)}{x^4}$$

Is there any way to get the right answer in Maple? (The power of $x$ must be $\lambda-4$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you see is correct. It's just not in the form you desire.

You can use Maple to modify the form, and there are several ways to accomplish that.

```
res := factor( diff( x^t, x$4 ) );

                         t                          
                        x  t (t - 1) (t - 2) (t - 3)
                 res := ----------------------------
                                      4             
                                     x              

combine( res );

                                            (t - 4)
                 t (t - 2) (t - 1) (t - 3) x       


combine( res, power );

                                            (t - 4)
                 t (t - 2) (t - 1) (t - 3) x       


simplify( res );

                                            (t - 4)
                 t (t - 2) (t - 1) (t - 3) x       

simplify( res, power );

                                            (t - 4)
                 t (t - 2) (t - 1) (t - 3) x
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'm a newbie in Maple, so this is simple with you but I don't know.,